# Trabalhando com arquivos SVG dinamicamente

Tags: html5, css3, firefox, svg

Estou desenvolvendo uma página Web onde utilizo inúmeros efeitos em CSS. entre um deles percebi que não consigo ultilizar os filtros no Firefox. Buscando pela internet encontrei algumas soluções que me dizem para usar arquivos SVG. O problema é quando preciso utilizar 2 filtros em um mesmo elemento, por exemplo inverter a cor de uma imagem e colocar sombra. No Chrome consigo fazer isso dessa maneira:

```
div img{
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%) drop-shadow(0.2em 0.1em 0.3em #000);
}
```

Ao utilizar 2 SVG no firefox, ele buga, as vezes mostra um efeito, as vezes mostra outro efeito, as vezes não mostra, como se ele dependesse de qual SVG for carregado por último e sobrepor o primeiro.

como resolver esse impasse?

---

Uma das `class` que utilizo para transformar uma imagem em preto e branco

```
.grayscale {
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
    filter: grayscale(100%);    
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

Comment: Existem várias formas de se adicionar [SVG no HTML](http://www.sitepoint.com/add-svg-to-web-page/), pode mostrar de que modo você faz?

Comment: @MarcosZolnowski Editei a pegunta e inseri a classe como solicitado.

Comment: @LeandroLUK você pode utilizar o [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) para postar um exemplo *funcionando*...  fica a dica (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Firefox ainda [não dá suporte a filtros CSS](http://caniuse.com/css-filters). Por isso, para aumentar a compatibilidade, você deve criar um `-webkit-filter` para funcionar no Chrome, Safari e outros navegadores baseados no WebKit, e um filtro SVG equivalente para o Firefox (como no seu exemplo do `.grayscale`).

Também não consegui aplicar dois filtros SVG em um mesmo elemento no Firefox de maneira direta. Você tem duas opções:

1. criar um filtro que combine os dois efeitos (ex.: invert e drop-shadow), ou
2. colocar a imagem dentro de um `<div>` e aplicar um filtro SVG na `<div>` (ex.: drop-shadow) e outro na imagem (invert).

Para a opção 1, você pode usar um programa de edição de arquivos SVG, como o [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/). Basta importar sua imagem, aplicar os filtros desejados (menu `Filters`), salvar como SVG, abrir o arquivo em um editor de texto e copiar a tag `<filter>` para dentro de um elemento `<svg>` em seu HTML.

A opção 2 pode ser ilustrada pelo exemplo a seguir:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
      .invert-shadow {
        /* Firefox */
        filter: url(#invert);
        /* Chrome, Safari */
        -webkit-filter: invert(100%) drop-shadow(0.2em 0.1em 0.3em #000);
      }
      .shadow {
        /* Firefox */
        filter: url(#shadow);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="shadow">
      <img class="invert-shadow" src="http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-logo-300.png" />
    </div>

    <svg>
      <filter id="invert">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" 
          values="-1  0  0 0 1 
                   0 -1  0 0 1 
                   0  0 -1 0 1
                   0  0  0 1 0"/>
      </filter>
      <filter id="shadow">
        <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="2" dy="2" />
        <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="1" />
        <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
      </filter>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```